# How can I change out an image using CamanJS?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, image-manipulation

I've got multiple images, and I'd like to load them each into a single `<canvas>` element at different points in time and then manipulate them using [CamanJS](http://camanjs.com/). I can get the first image to appear like this:

```
Caman('#canvas-element', '/images/one.jpg');
```

But then when I subsequently try to update that same element using the following code, it does not work.

```
Caman('#canvas-element', '/images/two.jpg');
```

Is there some way to reset/clear/flush the canvas and load new image data into it, or do I really need to create separate `<canvas>` elements for each image I want to load? I'd prefer a single element because I don't want to eat up all the memory.

Comment: This truly is just a wild guess!   Caman has a “replaceCanvas” method (in source code).  So, (1) Keep a reference to the Caman object [ var theCaman=Caman('#canvas-element', '/images/one.jpg'); ]  (2) Manually draw a new image into the canvas.  (3)  Fool Caman by asking it to replace the canvas with the same canvas [ theCaman.replaceCanvas(document.getElementById("canvas-element")); ]

Answer (score 16):

Remove the Caman attribute (data-caman-id) from the IMG or CANVAS element, change the image, and then re-render Caman.

```
document
  .querySelector('#view_image')
  .removeAttribute('data-caman-id');

const switch_img = '/to/dir/img.png';

Caman("#view_image", switch_img, function() {
  this.render();
});
```

Comment: Excellent thanks, `$("#view_image").removeAttr("data-caman-id");` was the real nugget here.

Comment: Spent several hours trying different ways, and only this worked!

Comment: Yes, it works... but your typo ('data-camen-id' - caman, not camen!) which I don't notice made me lose one hour...

Answer (score 4):

Hope followed code can help others who have same require.

```
function loadImage(source) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('image_id');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var image = new Image();
    image.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 960, 600);
    };
    image.src = source;
}

function change_image(source) {
    loadImage(source);
    Caman('#image_id', source, function () {
        this.reloadCanvasData();
         this.exposure(-10);
         this.brightness(5);
        this.render();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just figured this one out with a lot of trial and error and then a duh moment!

Instead of creating my canvas directly in my html, I created a container and then just did the following:

```
var retStr = "<canvas id=\"" + myName + "Canvas\"></canvas>";
document.getElementById('photoFilterCanvasContainer').innerHTML = retStr;

Caman("#" + myName + "Canvas", myUrl, function() {
    this.render();
});
```

You want the canvas id to be unique each time you access the Caman function with a new image.