# How to copy canvas image data into a paper.js Raster object

Tags: javascript, canvas, raster, paperjs, getimagedata

I'm trying to add Caman.js filter functionality to a paper.js Raster. And in order not to loose image information I want to reset the image data to the original data (_camanImageData) every time before I call Caman by copying it from a cloned raster. The code is like this:

```
with(paper) {
    Raster.prototype._camanImageData = null;
    Raster.prototype.filter = function(options) {

        var self = this,
            ctx = this.getContext(),  // caution! This also inits this._canvas (should).
            size = this._size;

        if( !this._camanOrgImage ) {
            this._camanOrgImage = this.clone(false);
        } else {
            var dst = ctx.createImageData(size.width, size.height);

            dst.data.set(this._camanOrgImage.getImageData(new Rectangle(0, 0, size.width, size.height)).data);
            this.setImageData(dst);
        }

        Caman(this._canvas, function () {

            for( option in options ) {
                var value = options[option];

                this[option](value);
            }

            this.render(function () {
                self._changed(129);
            });
        });
    };
}
```

The first call works fine. The second works apparently on the already modified data.

I call the filter function like this:

```
raster.filter({
    brightness: 50,
    saturation: 10,
    hue: 20,
});
```

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with Caman. Caman doesn't reload the changed canvas, if a "data-caman-id" attribute is set in the canvas element. Just delete this before the call to Caman and it works fine:

```
this._canvas.removeAttribute("data-caman-id");
Caman(this._canvas, function () {
    ...
```

The solution came from: [How can I change out an image using CamanJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15032973/how-can-i-change-out-an-image-using-camanjs)